# Why is Samwell Tarly considered a lord?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Having joined the Night's Watch, he forsook his rights to any land or titles. So why is he on the council with all the lords?

Comment: I would have answered with 'there is no more Night's Watch because there is no more need for a Night's watch', but that appears not to be the case.

Comment: I would suspect he helped with Tarly armies to attack King's landing after the main events of finale so he was given a seat in the Jury. He was not considered a lord.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I'd hesitantly suggest that 'join the nights watch' means 'go and live with the wildlings' now

Comment: No, his name actually *is* Samwell indeed. You'll notice GRRM tends to put a little twist on our common English names. Please don't roll back edits correcting this mistake.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sam was actually [appointed Grand Maester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samwell_Tarly#Season_8) ([senseless as that may be...](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212860/6365)), which grants him a place in the small council, **which presumably would also grant him presence (and a vote?) in what I assume is a short-staffed [Great Council](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212399/6365).**

[In the small council](https://youtu.be/_YNDWeni7e8?t=225), we see Sam all dressed in white, as is custom for Grand Maester, and Tyrion addresses him as "Grand Maester" too, just so we can make sure.

Comment: I haven't watched the episode yet but if it's not explicit at the trial scene it is at the small council scene at the end for anyone wondering.

Comment: I don't think he was appointed maester and the time of trial. It only happened after name of the king was declared.

Comment: Well, @HBhatia, he most certainly wasn't a lord, and I can't think of anything else that could justify him having a vote... I suppose the writers will have a good justification, given the ironclad writing this season's given us, though :)

Comment: The question is about the Council of Lords that chose the new king but this answer is referring to the Small Council meeting later in the episode.    The information in the answer is correct but does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: I added some emphasis, @krb — it's speculation, sure, but also the only reason I can find for Sam to be able to cast a vote.

Comment: @JNat The Onion Knight had a vote.  Ser Brienne had a vote, and she didn't rule anything in Westeros, nor was she set to inherit leadership where she did come from as I recall.  It didn't entirely seem to be a "Lords only" affair.

Comment: True, @zibadawatimmy: I'm glad they at least stopped short of giving _two_ Starks a vote... but short of that the whole thing's kind of a mess... :\

Comment: Ser Davos holds Rainwood in name of the Lord of Storm's End. And Brienne is the heir to Lord Selwyn Tarth, another prominent vassal of Baratheons. Brienne gets to vote for her father, Davos votes as Lord of Rainwood. (Not sure if Stannis raised him to Lordship in the show or is he still a landed knight - If he's a landed knight in the show, that might explain why he was unsure if he gets a vote or not)

Answer (score 3):

He was first in-line to succeed his father as head of House Tarly. Now the Night Watch's oath makes him abandon this claim, but it has also been made clear that under Daenerys' rule, he has been excused from his Night's Watch rule, because he was allowed to stay with Gilly, who is pregnant of his child (a big nono). It is made fairly clear everybody follows more or less Daenerys' decisions (Gendry also being there, Yara explicitly saying so). So it's fair to say according to this he also can re-claim his titles and thus would be Lord of Horn Hill. Obviously he later throws of this title again because he re-joins the citadel.

Note that Horn Hill is one of the mightiest houses of the Reach, maybe even the mightiest in-show since the Tyrells are gone and Florents seem to be irrelevant, so he could very well be seen as representative of the whole Reach, making him having one of the more important votes.

Comment: Her name is Gilly btw